# How to switch weather temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius in Facebook events

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

Facebook started showing the weather on event pages:

[image]

How to switch temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius? (or from Celsius to Fahrenheit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution for October 2014 (if you don't see a "Today" dropdown as in the marked solution)

Go in the **Settings** page of Facebook:

https://www.facebook.com/settings

[image]

Answer (score 7):

(OUTDATED see [firepol's solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/67852/1374))

---

1. Go to [your Events page](https://www.facebook.com/events/list)
2. In the upper right, click the gear:

   [image: screen shot]
3. Switch to Celsius:

   [image: screen shot]

Comment: At least for me (I see facebook differently, maybe because I'm a developer?) now, October 2014 I don't see any "Today" dropdown as shown in point 2 and it's impossible to me to find a "Settings" page to manage the Events temperature...